# Como pasar un estado a otro componente en react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

no sé mucho de react native, de hecho he comenzado a aprenderlo, pero me he topado con un problema que la verdad no le he encontrado solución, como hago para pasar un estado entre componentes, lo que hago es pasarlo por medio de los props, pero en el componente hijo me llega vacío y no he podido saber el porque, acá les explico un poco con el código.

Este es el componente padre

```
//importamos el componente hijo
import PlanetaTierra from './Componentes/Viewer/planetaTierra';

class App extends Component {
//creamos el constructor para utilizar los estados
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={ peso : ''  };
  }

  
  render() {
        return (

      <ScrollView >
        <View style={styles.bloquePeso}>
          <Text style={{color: 'white'}}>Ingresa tu peso en kg</Text>
           //tengo entendido que como esta en el onchangeText me modifica el valor que tengo en el estado
          <TextInput onChangeText={value => this.setState({peso})} keyboardType='numeric' style={styles.inputText} placeholderTextColor="white" >{peso}</TextInput>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.container}>
//y acá se lo paso al componente hijo
          <PlanetaTierra peso={this.state.peso}></PlanetaTierra>
        </View>
        
       
      
        
      </ScrollView>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

y acá esta el código del componente hijo en el cual me llega vacío

```
class PlanetaTierra extends Component{
    render(){
        const {peso} = this.props;
        console.log(this.props);

        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <View style={styles.bloquePeso}>
                    <Text style={{ color: 'white', paddingTop: 5 }}>Planeta Tierra</Text>
                </View>
    
                <View style={styles.bloqueImagenes}>
                    <Image style={{ width: 100, height: 100 }} source={require('../../src/img/planetaTierra.png')} />
                </View>
                <View style={styles.bloqueCarousel}>
                    <View style={{ flexDirection: 'column' }}>
                        <View style={styles.textoCarousel}>
                            <Text style={styles.texto}>{'Tu peso en este planeta \n es de :'+peso} </Text>
                        </View>
                        <View style={styles.textoCarousel}>
                            <Text style={styles.texto}>{'Se puede vivir hasta \n 80 años'} </Text>
                        </View>
                        <View style={styles.textoCarousel}>
                            <Text style={styles.texto}>Esta a 0 años luz </Text>
                        </View>
                    </View>
                    <View style={{ flexDirection: 'column' }}>
                        <View style={styles.textoCarousel}>
                            <Text style={styles.texto}>{'La vida del planeta es \n de 4543 millones de años'}</Text>
                        </View>
                        <View style={styles.textoCarousel}>
                            <Text style={styles.texto}>Esta en la vía lactea</Text>
                        </View>
                        <View style={styles.textoCarousel}>
                            <Text style={styles.texto}>La gravedad es de 9.807 m/s2</Text>
                        </View>
                    </View>
                </View>
                <View style={styles.bloqueTexto}>
                    <Text style={styles.texto}>Worchock Company</Text>
                </View>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

espero que me puedan ayudar con este tema ya que me encuentro en fase de aprendizaje y sí me recomiendan algún curso en base a esto, estaré muy agredecido

Comment: Hola, para poder utilizar el `import PlanetaTierra from ...` te hace falta exportar la clase al final de su definición `class PlanetaTierra extends Component{ ... } export default PlanetaTierra;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay que modificar la configuración del elemento `TextInput`:

```
<TextInput
      onChangeText={text => this.setState({peso:text})}
      value={value}
      />
```

Solo te faltaba asignar el valor de `input` a la propiedad `peso` del objeto `state`, que viene dada por `text` en el método `onChangeText`.

> onChangeText :Callback that is called when the text input's text changes. Changed text is passed as a single string argument to the callback handler.

Puedes consultar la referencia con la [version hooks](https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput) de `TextInput`.

Nota: aseguarte de exportar el componente `PlanetaTierra`, al final de su archivo, tu ejemplo no lo tiene y asumo que se te paso agregarlo, no creo que este fue la causa del error, pues React se hubiera quejado antes de dejarte continuar con la operación del `TextInput`.

Comment: Muchas gracias bro, si era eso

Comment: Qué bien, si consideras la respuesta como valida, vota por ella y acéptala, asi se mantiene el sitio bien documentado, Suerte y salud!